# Работа с Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Ребята, до это я работал с [960.gs](http://960.gs) - там во время разработки все клетки-ячейки выделаны 1 пиксельным бордером, что упрощало разработку. Сейчас начал щупать bootstrap - все подключил как надо, но при вставке примеров сетки визуально не вижу, хотя все встает правильно. Как думаете, что не так? Может оно так и должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так добавьте в css

```
.row div {

border:1px solid gray;

}
```

а если хотите, можете добавить бордер всем классам spanN

Answer (score 0):

так и должно быть